# Difference between memcpy and '=' when copying simple struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, memcpy

Consider copy a simple struct which doesn't require special copy semantics.

```
struct A
{
    char i
    int i;
    long l;
    double b;
    //...maybe more member
}
struct A a;
a.c = 'a'; //skip other member just for illustrate
struct A b;
memset(&a, 0, sizeof(a));
b.c = a.c;
//...for other members, the first way to assign
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b)); //the second way
b = a;    //the third way
```

The 3 methods do the same thing, and it seems all of them are correct. I used to use 'memcpy' for copying simple structs, but seems now '=' can do the same thing. So is there any difference between using `memcpy` and '='?

Comment: `memcpy` will copy the padding between members.

Comment: `memset` : memset(addres of object, set char, size)

Comment: @Barmar And `=` may or may not; it's up to the implementation.

Comment: It does not seem to be fixed.

Comment: @Barmar, you mean for the reason of memory aligned, memcpy copy and padding but '=' will not?

Comment: The difference between those three ways, I guess, depends on the structure to be copied and the programming language you are using.

Comment: `memcpy()` can also be convenient for copying an array of structs in one go.

Comment: @Dmitri, yes, agree with that point about copy array. tks.

Comment: With floating point NaN, I do not think that `a = b` must _always_ give the same bit-for-bit copy.  Further `memcpy()` forces a variable to exist in memory and not a register.

Comment: Depending on your definition of simple, you might be violating `memcpy`'s contract. For example, having a `std::string` member will not need a deep copy, yet `memcpy` will not be a good idea.

Comment: @chux Copying a NaN must certainly result in the same NaN. And I wouldn't worry about structs in registers.

Comment: @Jim Balter 1) Could not a signaling NaN invoke a handler just by doing the `a = b` assignment?  Of course a `memcpy()` would not.  2) are not structures of diminutive size allowed to be passed in registers?

Comment: @chux a) I'm not sure but I think signaling NaNs only raise exceptions when operands of arithmetic operators, not assignment -- but if they do raise exceptions, you won't get any sort of copy at all; if they are copied, it will be bit-for-bit. b) Yes, they can be; I just said I wouldn't worry about them.

Comment: @Jim Balter In general about (a), I agree that bit-for-bit copy is the usual & expected, but with FP types ([80-bit double Pseudo Denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) and [decimal base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) ) there are sometimes multiple bit representations for the same value & a copy going though some Math processor may emit a preferred one.  All somewhat esoteric situations.  C rarely defines this detail & I suspect the door is open for `a = b` results in the same value, but differing bit patterns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`memcpy` treats the structure as a contiguous array of bytes, and just copies all of them. As a result, it will always copy the padding bytes after members.

`=` is only required to copy the members. It might or might not copy the padding.

Comment: tks, Barmar, is that means '=' is the same as b.c = a.c ...etc?

Comment: Yes, that's the required semantics. It might be optimized into different code -- the compiler could turn it into something like `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the three methods -- manually assigning each member, assigning the entire struct, or using memcpy -- will result in all the members of `b` being the same as the corresponding members of `a`, which is all you should care about. The potential differences are in the value of pad bytes -- `memcpy` will copy them, assigning individual members won't, and assigning the entire struct may or may not -- it's up to the implementation. Some implementations will just use `memcpy` to assign structs, some will assign member by member, and some will do one or the other depending on such factors as the size of the struct.

I recommend using struct assignment -- it's the simplest, the shortest, and the most problem-oriented. Leave the implementation details up to the compiler. Also, in C++ you can define the assignment operator yourself for greater control and flexibility, and memcpy is frowned on and can have bad effects with classes (see JaredPar's answer).

Comment: @JasonC The list is the OP's, who is asking about C (but is interested in programming in C++ in the future). And the copy constructor won't necessarily result in the members of `b` being the same as the members of `a`, unlike the other three methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would get in the habit now of using `=` instead of `memcpy`.  In C the difference is minimal at best but once you graduate to C++, as indicated by the question, the difference is huge.  Consider for example

```
struct C {
  C() { }
  ~C() { } 
}

C local1;
C local2;
memcpy(&local2, &local1, sizeof(C));
```

In this case the the constructor for `local2` is run at the declaration point.  However the destructor for that value is never run.  Instead it's members are magically replaced with `memcpy` and the destructor is run on the `memcpy` bits.  If `C` happened to allocate any resources this can easily lead to leaks.